# Authenticate to Azure Artifacts using Azure CLI

Tags: python, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-artifacts

In my company, we use Azure Artifacts for managing Python packages, and `poetry` for managing the environment. The standard documentation mentions using `artifacts-keyring`. This works fine when developing locally, but when building Docker images this doesn't work.

For CI/CD we've fixed it using a PAT, by constructing our Dockerfile like this (excerpt):

```
ARG PAT 
RUN poetry config http-basic.azure u $PAT 
RUN poetry install
```

And in our pipeline, have the following task:

```yaml
- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build image 
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    containerRegistry: $(registry)
    repository: $(repository)
    arguments: --build-arg PAT=$(System.Accesstoken)
```

This works. Yay!

For local development, we could build the image like so:

```bash
docker build --build-arg PAT=$(az account get-access-token --query accessToken) .
```

Used to work like a charm, but since today it doesn't. If I manually create a PAT in Azure DevOps, and pass that, it works.

Did anything change? I really liked this setup, and would love for it to work again!

**EDIT**

Ok, I left out an important piece of information. It works when I run the command in Powershell, but not in Ubuntu on WSL2. Anybody have an idea why not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using a subexpression in PowerShell to make the call to get the access token - `$(az account get-access-token --query accessToken)` - and that may be why it's not working in bash on Ubuntu in WSL. Try setting that part of the code to a variable separately, then use the variable in your `docker build` line so that you're passing the actual token and not the az command to query it.

Comment: Oh wow, could I have been that stupid haha

Comment: Hmm... it looks like thats not the problem. The command gives me the token. I found a different way around it now, by using poetry and connecting that to the credential manager.